# CallerMemberName parameter is blank for a specific method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, runtime

I have the following Log method (for a Unit Test project):

```
        public static void WriteLogFile<T>(T obj, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string callingMethod = "")
        {
#if WRITELOGFILE
            var path = Path.Combine(LogFileLocation, callingMethod + ".json");
            var content = (typeof(T) == typeof(string)) ? (obj as string) : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

            File.WriteAllText(path, content);
#endif
        }
```

And I use it in the following `TestMethod`:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestGetUserInfoAsync()
{
    //var tokenFile = TestUtils.GetLogFileLocation(nameof(this.TestRedeemTokensAsync2));
    var tokenFile = @"D:\Temp\TestLog\TestRedeemTokensAsync2.json";
    var accessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(File.ReadAllText(tokenFile))
        .access_token.ToString();

    var result = await GoogleService.GetUserInfoAsync(this.systemConfig,
       accessToken);
    TestUtils.WriteLogFile(result);

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

I have other 3 Test Methods and they all runs correctly, and they all have async/await Tasks, writing log files with the filenames taken from the method names.

However, for the above specific method, the parameter `callingMethod` is an empty string (not null). The result file is a file named `.json` (it is a valid file in Windows). I am not sure if this is related to Unit Test project only.

Why is it happening? How can I debug in this case?

Additional information: I thought it may be because I added the following method, and the 1st calling mess up:

```
public static string GetLogFileLocation([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string callingMethod = "")
{
    var path = Path.Combine(LogFileLocation, callingMethod + ".json");
    return path;
}
```

However, I tried removing it and use hard string for file path (as you see in my code above) instead, but the problem persist.

EDIT: I added the Stack Trace that may be useful. I notice there is a [External Code] row between the code. I don't know what causes it.

[image]

EDIT2: The IL code indeed has problem: the 4 (sorry, 4, not 3) other `TestMethod`s are running fine, and their IL code is correct, like this:

[image]

However, the method I am having problem with, I don't see any function call. The only `WriteLogFile` I can see is this one, but it is a string:

[image]

Full IL code here: http://pasted.co/cf4b0ea7

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: Are other test methods (that run correctly) in the same dll (VS project) as test method which fails?

Comment: It should work, meaning the error probably isn't posted. Debug.

Comment: Thanks, added the screenshot (sorry for over-cautious blurring the names, just to be safe because this is a project for my client). I think the Stack Trace explains why the empty string, but I don't know why or what causes it.
The other 3 `TestMethod`s are in the same file. I tried debugging the other methods, the calls in Stack Trace are immediately one after another.

Comment: Debugging will not help, because `CallerMemberName` is compile-time feature. That is, compiler sees that attribute and replaces all calls to `TestUtils.WriteLogFile(result);` to `TestUtils.WriteLogFile(result, "MethodNameHere");`, at compile time.

Comment: Try to extract the IL and see if there is anything.

Comment: @Evk and PatrickHofman: thank you, your advice is indeed helpful. I have added the IL. I don't know why I get different IL result from the same code. This is in Debug build, no optimization. Can you see why it is happening?

Comment: Possibly async stuff. Can you try to rewrite that part to be non-async and see if it still persists?

Comment: @PatrickHofman found the problem when I was changing it to synchronous one. In my code, result was actually `dynamic` (because I accidentally left `accessToken` as `dynamic`), hence the reason. So the problem was with `CallerMemberName` AND `dynamic` AND async. Remove either `dynamic` or async fixed the problem.

Comment: Strange..........

Comment: Dynamic makes sense, but I don't think async is related. I mean I believe changing it fixes problem, but probably not specifically because of async to sync change.

Comment: Sorry a bit late now, tomorrow I will try to look at the IL of either case (async only and dynamic only) and see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just had a similar problem. In my case `CallerMemberName` was `null` because I was specifying the attribute for method implementing the interface, but not on the interface definition itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be happening with `async` and `dynamic` going together. Remove either one (switch to synchronous or casting into a strongly typed variable) fix the problem:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestGetUserInfoAsync()
{
    //var tokenFile = TestUtils.GetLogFileLocation(nameof(this.TestRedeemTokensAsync2));
    var tokenFile = @"D:\Temp\TestLog\TestRedeemTokensAsync2.json";
    var accessToken = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(File.ReadAllText(tokenFile))
        .access_token.ToString()) as string; // Here, cast this to string instead of keeping it as dynamic

    var result = await GoogleService.GetUserInfoAsync(this.systemConfig,
       accessToken);
    TestUtils.WriteLogFile(result);

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```